# context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"] returning empty value

Tags: authentication, .net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a .net core 2.2 web api with custom authentication scheme but I'm not able to read the content of my http request containing an authorization parameter.
I've created the following attribute:

```
    [AttributeUsage(validOn: AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ApiKeyAuthAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {

        var auth = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        await next();
    }
}
```

Then I decorated the calls with the "[ApiKeyAuthAttribute]"
The attribute is called but "auth" is always empty.
I've inspected the http call and it contains the following string:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/secret HTTP/1.1
Authorization: hmacauth 65d3a4f0-0239-404c-8394-21b94ff50604:YasPG+z7r1jyUUqAlXY9G91Ov0IfDfA9sNvW4NLocIU=:4977ca7250414e9c8c8b3d9a703fcf9e:1596303518
Host: localhost:5000
```

I guess that I've to put something in the application startup but I'm not sure..

This is my current application startup

```
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: I also tried to add Authentication / Authorization to app and services in the startup file but nothing changed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get the Authorization header using this function:

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out StringValues authString);
```